# Wakanda kills Safari on IOS and OSX

Tags: ios, macos, safari, crash, wakanda

My Wakanda based application simply kills Safari on OSX or IOS since november 2015 ( release 11, maybe 10 ). It does not impact Chrome or Firefox, just webkit based browsers. 
As soon as the web app is reached by webkit, memory usage explodes, both on Ipad or laptop.
There is nothing that could explain that in my code. It was working fine before the latest Wakanda upgrades.

It may be funny because of the Wakanda vs Safari stuff, but definitely, my customers do not appreciate that.

Am I alone with such problems on webkit? It looks like a bug in Wakanda server. 
FYI, both wakander-server on linux and OSX give the same result.

Please help.

Comment: If it is Safari who crashes and not Wakanda Server how can this be a Wakanda Server related problem ?
And I think this is more a bug report that should be filed on Wakanda's ticketing system.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a prototype page? Did you use any custom widget?

It will be more helpful if you can post the exact build of your wakanda server. You could get that in studio by clicking "About Wakanda Enterprise Studio ". Or you call `waf.BUILD` in prototype pages.

I agree with @hamzahik. Since Wakanda Server is used as a REST server, the crashing in Safari is probably more related to widgets and front-end frameworks used in your application. I also recommend you submit a Wakanda support ticket so you can upload your solution to Wakanda team privately for them to test it.

Comment: No, it is not a prototype page. It do not use custom widgets but home made SVG based widgets which requests the wakandadb via REST. The build is the latest one : 11.197492